# Efficient way to manually calculate the eigenvectors of radical eigenvalues.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, radicals

Suppose some matrix $\mathbf A$ has a radical eigenvalue $\lambda$. To find a corresponding eigenvector $\mathbf v$ one can do Gaussian Elimination on the system of simultaneous linear equations represented by the matrix $\mathbf A- \lambda\mathbf I$. The presence of radicals along the diagonal makes this a cumbersome and tedious process. Is there a more efficient way to ***MANUALLY*** calculate $\mathbf v$ ?

My math (engineering) professor recommended something he calls the *method of Grassmann-Steinitz* in case of irrational eigenvalues. However, searching the internet turns up nothing by that name.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Grassmann-Steinitz is an exchange theorem, which states if you've got two bases of a finite dimensional Vectorspace, you can exchange vectors from one basis to the other.

Comment: If the characteristic polynomial looks like $\lambda (1-\lambda)(\lambda + \sqrt 6) (\lambda - \sqrt 6) $ then $\sqrt 6$ is an eigenvalue of the given matrix.

Comment: Ok, it doesnt change anything, why you could'nt apply gaussian. This way always finds the solution. More effcient ways to calculate v: What you have to do is solving a linear system of course there are others and sometimes cheaper methods (e.g. cramer's rule, which you cannot apply here) but I don't think there are more efficient solvers, for general A.

Comment: Okay. What you said kind of confirms my intuition that there is no great advantage from using some novel scheme to solve the system. By analogy, it might be like the difference in efficiency between short division and long division. Thanks for the feedback.